# How to change Audio track in Google Chrome Cast V2

Tags: javascript, chromecast

We are using custom V2 SDk receiver for our Google ChromeCast development.

Our streaming Videos have multiple Audio Tracks to play audio in different languages. I don't see any API details to change Audio track in a different language.

Is there any API in V2 SDk receiver  to change Audio track of a video?

I see `getAudioTrackManager()` available with CAF Reciever SDK but couldn't find anything in V2 SDK.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a shaka-player? If yes, please check this related issue in [github](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/544).

Comment: Do you have any success with chromecast audio track switch?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a `LoadRequest` with a new set of `activeTrackIds`:

```js
var s = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
var m = s.getMediaSession().media;
req = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(m);
req.activeTrackIds = [2]; // You can find available tracks in m.tracks
s.loadMedia(req);
```